# Does this "could" refer to the past: "They could unknowingly hit an animal in the dark, so they went home early"

Tags: modal-verbs, past-tense

Do we use "could" the way used in the sentence below -when we want the sentence to refer to the past?

> they **could** unknowingly hit an animal in the dark, so they went home early.

I was searching about uses of 'could' and 'might', and the results were like it is usually referring to the present and "could have" seems to refer to the past until present.

[Source](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/can-or-could)

Answer (score 1):

Your last sentence is right: "Could have" refers to the past, "could" refers to a possible present or future. Since the quoted sentence says they "went home early", it would be better to say "could have" instead of could. "Could" alone might also appear in a clause about a prior conversation.

Here are some good ways to rephrase the quoted sentence:

- They **could have** unknowingly hit an animal in the dark, so they **went** home early.
- They **could** unknowingly hit an animal in the dark, so they **are going** home early.
- She **convinced** him they **could** unknowingly hit an animal in the dark, so they **went** home early.
- They **could have** unknowingly hit an animal in the dark, so they **should have** gone home early.
- They **could** unknowingly hit an animal in the dark, so they **should** go home early.

In the above, every instance of "could" could be replaced with "might" instead, and it would still be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I understand "could hit an animal" as "it would be possible that they hit an animal" and as they wanted to avoid this they went home early.